# twitter bootstrap prepended input does not work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I copied prepended input from twitter bootstrap examples but it does not work properly. What is the problem?

```
<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on">@</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="prependedInput" class="span2"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jGbFt/

Comment: Can you share the link to the bootstrap example you got this from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use code from bootstrap 2.3.2 and linking to the bootstrap 3 css file, you can change your css to link to

```
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
```

and it will work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/jGbFt/2/)